# Unexpected 'if' inside array. Laravel

Tags: if-statement, laravel-5

I'm trying to filter values that will be inside array. For that I used following syntax:

```
$selected = array(

        if ($request->annual!=0) {
            'annual' => $request->annual,
        }
        if ($request->registration!=0) {
            'registration' => $request->registration,
        }
        if ($request->monthly!=0) {
            'monthly' => $request->registration,
        }
        if ($request->exam!=0) {
            'exam' => $request->exam,
        }
        if ($request->laboratory!=0) {
            'laboratory' => $request->laboratory,
        }
        if ($request->computer_lab!=0) {
            'computer_lab' => $request->computer_lab,
        }  
    );
```

But it is throwing syntax error.

```
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'
```

What is the problem here? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP not allowed IF directly in Array body.

Assign array values as following:

```
    $selected = array();
    if ($request->annual != 0) {
        $selected['annual'] = $request->annual;
    }
    if ($request->registration != 0) {
        $selected['registration'] = $request->registration;
    }
    if ($request->monthly != 0) {
        $selected['monthly'] = $request->monthly;
    }
    if ($request->annual != 0) {
        $selected['annual'] = $request->annual;
    }
```